# MySQL - Best way to get only CVCV values?

Tags: php, mysql, pattern-matching

I have a database table with lots and lots of words and strings. (Right now it has over 300K entries, but it grows.) What would be the best way to get only those values that fit the **pattern**? Lets say the table is:

```
apples
oranges
abba
car
real
tipi
riot
tidy
```

Now how to retrieve only pattern CVCV (ConsonantVowelConsonantVowel)? Or CVVC, LLLL (letter*4), etc? I could just make a column with different patterns like so:

```
word: real
patterns: LLLL,CVVC,LVVC,LVVL,LVLC,LLVC,LLLC,LVLL,CLLC,...
```

and search the database with "SELECT * FROM table WHERE word LIKE $pattern", but I was thinking if there is a better way?

Answer (score 2):

**CVCV:**

```
SELECT 'cara' REGEXP '[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz][aeiouy][bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz][aeiouy]';
```

true

```
SELECT 'abba' REGEXP '[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz][aeiouy][bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz][aeiouy]';
```

false

Comment: +1 Just not so much searching as scanning. :) If you're doing this often, you may as well pre-calculate the pattern type for each and store that too.

Answer (score -2):

If you're only looking for 4 letter words than that should be fairly simple to do with a regexp condition.  For example, if you don't care what the order of the vowels and the consonants are, then it's as simple as this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourTable
WHERE yourField REGEXP '^[a-z]{4}$'
```

All this says is find a word that starts and ends with 4 letters a-z.

****Note**** This only applies to lowercase letters using this pattern, if you're  worried about uppercase letters you can either do:

```
1) LOWER(yourField) REGEXP '^[a-z]{4}$'

OR

2) yourField REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z]{4}$'
```

---

If you would like something similar to this but not quite what I gave you, read up on regular expressions.  This is a pretty good starter reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

I would suggest you read up on regular expressions a little anyway as they are pretty powerful and fairly useful in a lot of instances of string manipulation.

Comment: The question very clearly stated that they are looking for various specific orderings of vowels and consonants (such as CVCV).

Comment: @siride If you notice the OP said "Or CVVC, LLLL (letter*4), etc?" which my answer clearly covers LLLL.  That's just ONE example yes, but one that they did mention.